# VS2019 RegPkg.exe throws Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I've just installed Visual Studio 2019 with SDK and when i try to run RegPkg.exe, I see the following error. I don't have any other VS instances installed on the machine but I'm confused why the error is reporting about version 15.0.0.0 (which is VS2017).

Can someone please help me to resolve this error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.RegPkg.Main(String[] arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed I got the exact same error message, using VS 2017's version. So it has nothing to do with the version you are using. I don't even have 2019 installed.

Microsoft simply broke their SDK, which has apparently been broken for 2 years, and no one noticed. For reference, I'm using VS 2017 15.9.7, also with the VSSDK installed.

I have a NuGet reference to that DLL in a VSIX extension I build, so I had a copy in my .nuget package cache ("%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.shell.framework\15.9.28307\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework.dll"). I copied that version into the folder where regpkg.exe is located, and resolved the error (%VSSDK150INSTALL%\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin).

Probably not the best solution, but Microsoft needs to fix their product. I suspect it broke as part of their reorganization for the 2017 product, as they also added all the assemblies that extensions need for dependencies to NuGet. I guess they forgot to keep that assembly in the actual VS install folder.

EDIT: I've been looking into this more, and apparently the file actually exists in the lib sub folder right there with the exe. However none of the versions I've found actually work with CreatePkgDef.exe which was my backup plan, as it now throws this error instead:

> CreatePkgDef : error : ArgumentException: No Visual Studio
>   registration attribute found in this assembly. The assembly should
>   contain an instance of the attribute
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationAttribute' defined in
>   assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework' version '15.0.0.0'

Seems to work with regpkg.exe, though I haven't tried every combination of options.